# Different Form apparence in Windows Forms Application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer, .net-5

In my VB.net Windows Forms App, I designed it with this apparence:

[image: Apparence i designed]

But when I open it, the apparence is:

[image: How it appears]

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: You app is not DpiAware and VisualStyles are disabled.

Comment: BTW, this usually happens when you disable `Application Framework` and you don't create an initialization procedure (where you add `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` and `Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false)`). You should also subscribe to the new `ApplyHighDpiMode` event (MyApplication). I suggest to set `e.HighDpiMode = HighDpiMode.PerMonitorV2`

Comment: Or call `Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.PerMonitorV2)`. Same thing.

Comment: What's the double headed arrow in the titlebar in the second pic?

Comment: Some of the controls have Enable = False.